# How to create a python script that works with python3 and 2

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin, python3, catkin-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the install space, python scripts have their shebang changed to the version specified with `PYTHON_EXECUTABLE`. In the devel workspace this also happens for globally installed scripts. But when I run a normal script with rosrun, it will take the version specified in the shebang. **How can I create a script that works in both python versions in the devel space?**

I could change the shebang to `python3` but then it's not backwards compatible. I would like to have this handled automatically.

<s>Is this a good solution?</s>

```
#!/usr/bin/env python$ROS_PYTHON_VERSION
```

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python$ROS_PYTHON_VERSION’: No such file or directory
```

**EDIT**
I found that REP-151 will describe the path for switching from Python 2 to Python 3 in ROS 1. It's still WIP, but I found some answers there.
https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/201/files

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334621/how-to-create-a-python-script-that-works-with-python3-and-2/) by [Rayman](https://answers.ros.org/users/46652/rayman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2019-10-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a documentation about [UsingPython3](http://wiki.ros.org/UsingPython3) in the ROS wiki, with one specific section towards [changing the shebang](http://wiki.ros.org/UsingPython3/SourceCodeChanges#Changing_shebangs).

Does that help?

P.S: This documentation has been announced recently on [discourse](https://discourse.ros.org/t/how-can-i-help-with-noetic/10859) and as they say:

> While it has had a few reviewers, I think this is the first time it’s been linked publicly, so if you have a wiki account please fix any issues you find.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rayman](https://answers.ros.org/users/46652/rayman/) on 2020-07-03**:
PR https://github.com/ros/catkin/pull/1044 greatly improves working with python2/3 due to automatically rewriting the shebang to the wanted python version. Now it's possible to follow the wiki.